# MongoDB block needs to be deployed in 2 times?

Tags: mongodb, azure, terraform

I'm trying to deploy a Terraform script, which worked while I was building it, because at that time, I created a resource block, and deployed it, and up to the next, and in that order, everything was fine.
But now, I'm trying to deploy it all at once, from zero.
The issue is with following code block:

```
resource "mongodbatlas_project_ip_access_list" "allowed_ips" {
  for_each = toset(concat(
    var.allowed_ips,
    flatten([for web_app in data.azurerm_linux_web_app.web_apps : web_app.outbound_ip_address_list])
  ))
  project_id = mongodbatlas_project.project.id
  ip_address = each.value
}
```

I'm getting some IP's from a web app that is being deployed by another moduele, but in the same pipeline. If I deploy the mongodb when the webapp allready is running, the deployment is fine, but like now, when I try to deploy both the webapp and the mongodb, it's not working out, getting this error:

```
│ Error: Invalid for_each argument
│ 
│   on modules\mongodb\main.tf line 71, in resource "mongodbatlas_project_ip_access_list" "allowed_ips":
│   71:   for_each = toset(concat(
│   72:     var.allowed_ips,
│   73:     flatten([for web_app in data.azurerm_linux_web_app.web_apps : web_app.outbound_ip_address_list])
│   74:   ))
│     ├────────────────
│     │ data.azurerm_linux_web_app.web_apps is object with 1 attribute "api"
│     │ var.allowed_ips is list of string with 2 elements
│ 
│ The "for_each" set includes values derived from resource attributes that
│ cannot be determined until apply, and so Terraform cannot determine the
│ full set of keys that will identify the instances of this resource.
│ 
│ When working with unknown values in for_each, it's better to use a map
│ value where the keys are defined statically in your configuration and where
│ only the values contain apply-time results.
│ 
│ Alternatively, you could use the -target planning option to first apply
│ only the resources that the for_each value depends on, and then apply a
│ second time to fully converge.
```

I can get the solution of deploying in two separate times, but I would really like it to be deployable at once.
Any workaround?

Comment: Can you share the modules as well? @pieter-jan goeman

Answer (score 0):

After a workaround on your issue, I found a way that instead of using dynamic `foreach` loop or function, use `count` function to creates an instance/s based on the length of a list/set and also

> It simplifies the creation of multiple resource instances without having to repeat the same resource block multiple times.

Refer [blog](https://spacelift.io/blog/terraform-count-for-each) by @[Jack Roper](https://spacelift.io/blog/author/jackr) for more relevant information.

```bash
count = length(toset(concat( var.allowed_ips, 
flatten([for web_app in data.azurerm_linux_web_app.web_apps : web_app.outbound_ip_address_list]))))
```

Once it is defined, use [`element Function`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/element) to obtain each element from the list by providing an index as shown in the document.

```bash
ip_address = element(toset(concat( var.allowed_ips, 
flatten([for web_app in data.azurerm_linux_web_app.web_apps : web_app.outbound_ip_address_list]))), count.index)
```

Comment: I see that this would be another way to do this, but do you think it would also solve my issue?

Comment: Yes, it will. Can you try once? @pieter-jangoeman